# Tmux prints u'0x001b' and “]112” in vim when tmux prefix pressed

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

I have an issue with tmux, similar to [tmux printing u'0x001b' and "]112" randomly](https://superuser.com/questions/864364/tmux-printing-u0x001b-and-112-randomly) but not the same, because it only happens inside vim, and when I press Ctrl-a (my tmux prefix).

I updated `libvte`, tried another terminal emulator (currently Terminator, GNOME Terminal and XFCE Terminal), and the issue persists.

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.1
```

Vim version:

```
8.0.1505
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 with i3wm
```

My tmux configuration:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
# Set scrollback history to 10k
set -g history-limit 10000

# Set Ctrl-a to default prefix key combination
# and unbind C-b to free it up
set -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b

# use send-prefix to pass C-a through to app
bind C-a send-prefix

# shorten command delay
set -sg escape-time 1

# set window and pane index to 1
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

# reload ~/.tmux.conf using prefix r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

# use PREFIX | to split horizontally and PREFIX - to split vertically
bind | split-window -h
bind - split-window -v

# Make the current window the first window
bind T swap-window -t 1

# map Vi movement keys as pane movement keys
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# and use C-h and C-l to cycle thru panes
bind -r C-h select-window -t :-
bind -r C-l select-window -t :+

# resize panes using PREFIX {H, J, K, L}
bind H resize-pane -L 5
bind J resize-pane -D 5
bind K resize-pane -U 5
bind L resize-pane -R 5

# -------------------
# Copy & Paste
# -------------------

#provide access to the clipboard for pbpaste, pbcopy
set-option -g default-command "zsh"
set-window-option -g automatic-rename on

# use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi

# set 'v' to begin selection as in Vim
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard"

# update default binding of 'Enter' to also use copy-pipe
unbind -T copy-mode-vi Enter
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe "xclip -selection clipboard"

bind y run 'tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard'
bind C-y run 'tmux save-buffer - | xclip -selection clipboard'

#--------------
# Status Bar
#--------------
set-option -g status on
set-option -g status-interval 2
set-option -g status-justify "centre"

setw -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity on

# Colors

set-window-option -g window-status-fg brightblue #base0
set-window-option -g window-status-bg colour236
set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg brightred #orange
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg colour236
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

# Hostname and IP on left status bar
set-option -g status-left-length 80
set-option -g status-right-length 120
set-option -g status-left "#(~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left)"
set-option -g status-right "#(~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh right)"
bind C-[ run '~/tmux-powerline/mute_powerline.sh left'      # Mute left statusbar.
bind C-] run '~/tmux-powerline/mute_powerline.sh right'     # Mute right statusbar.

#### COLOUR (Solarized 256)

# default statusbar colors
set-option -g status-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g status-fg colour136 #yellow
set-option -g status-attr default

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-fg colour244 #base0
set-window-option -g window-status-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-attr dim

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-fg colour166 #orange
set-window-option -g window-status-current-bg default
set-window-option -g window-status-current-attr bright

# pane border
set-option -g pane-border-fg colour235 #base02
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg colour240 #base01

# message text
set-option -g message-bg colour235 #base02
set-option -g message-fg colour166 #orange

# pane number display
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour33 #blue
set-option -g display-panes-colour colour166 #orange

# mouse
set-option -g mouse on

# clock
set-window-option -g clock-mode-colour colour64 #green
# bell
set-window-option -g window-status-bell-style fg=colour235,bg=colour160 #base02, red
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour235, bg=colour27]⮀#[fg=colour255, bg=colour27] #I ⮁ #W #[fg=colour27, bg=colour235]⮀"
set-window-option -g window-status-format "#[fg=colour27, bg=colour235]⮀#[fg=colour255, bg=colour235] #I ⮁ #W #[fg=colour27, bg=colour235]⮀"

# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
 # for vim
set -g @resurrect-strategy-vim 'session'
set -g @resurrect-processes '"~rails server" "~npm start"'
source "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf"

# Other examples:
# set -g @plugin 'github_username/plugin_name'
# set -g @plugin 'git@github.com/user/plugin'
# set -g @plugin 'git@bitbucket.com/user/plugin'
set-option -g terminal-overrides ',xterm*:Cr=\E]12;gray\007'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```